# How to replace the '\\' in a directory with '/'?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I wanted to replace the backslashes in the directory with  a  forward slash. Currently, this program just terminates, so I'm not exactly sure what to do. I would appreciate any input/assistance!

```
def fix(result):
    '''this will correct the \\ in directory by replacing with  /'''
    result=['C:/Users/SO\\Downloads\\myfile.txt']
    li=list(result[0])
    for i in range(len(li)):
        if li[i]== '\\':
            li[i]= '/' 
            return li[1:]
    s="".join(li)
    print (s)
```

Comment: btw, try not to name a variable in your function the same as the parameter

Comment: @Neil what operating system do you use?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To easily replace a substring in a string `txt`with another:

```
txt = txt.replace('\\', '/') #Replacing \\ with /
```

> Remember kids, python has a built in function for **everything**

Comment: This would be okay if `li` was a string and not a list, yeah?

Comment: Oh, oops. Of course `li` is a string. I'm going to edit my answer right now. Sorry!!

Comment: To your defense, it's quite a silly list  with only one item. But (grasping for possible reasons unmentioned by the OP) just maybe the list in the actual code is longer.